# how to send a complex object to a jsp

Tags: jsp

My java classes are :

```
public class Name{

  private String name;
  private ArrayList<Phone> phoneList;

  // plus getters and setters
}

public class Phone{

      private String phone;

      // plus getters and setters
}
```

Supose i have an ArrayList of Name, like:

```
ArrayList<Name> nameList = some method that returns an ArrayList<Name>
```

My servlet code would be:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  ArrayList<Name> nameList = some method that returns an ArrayList<Name>

  request.setAttribute("nameList", nameList);
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("someJSP.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

my jsp code would be:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty requestScope['nameList'] }">
    <c:forEach var="name" items="${requestScope[' nameList '] }">
      Name:${name.name }
        <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${not empty requestScope[' nameList.phoneList'] }">
            <c:forEach var="phone" items="${requestScope ['nameList.phoneList'] }">
              Phone:${phone.phone } </div>
            </c:forEach>
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
         <span>The phone list is empty.</span>
          </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

When i run the jsp file the nameList is not empty but the phone list is empty.

Somehow the phone list is lost and i don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

**When i run the jsp file the nameList is not empty but the pone list is empty.**,

Because you didnt set the value for the `ponelist`

**Somehow the phone list is lost**

It is not lost you dont have any method in the servlet to return the value from the getters and setters,

```
  ArrayList<Name> nameList = some method that returns an ArrayList<Name>    
  request.setAttribute("nameList", nameList);
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("someJSP.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);
```

So need to have another list and set the attribute for the class `Phone` like the same above,

```
  ArrayList<Phone> poneList = some method that returns an ArrayList<Phone>
  request.setAttribute("ponelist", ponelist);
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: When i do that i only get one phoneList and i need the phoneList of every object contained in the nameList.

Answer (score 0):

i've found the solution.

The problem was in the condition of the second c:when and c:foreach.
I was doing this:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty requestScope['nameList'] }">
    <c:forEach var="name" items="${requestScope[' nameList '] }">
      Name:${name.name }
        <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${not empty requestScope[' nameList.phoneList'] }">
            <c:forEach var="phone" items="${requestScope ['nameList.phoneList'] }">
              Phone:${phone.phone } </div>
            </c:forEach>
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
         <span>The phone list is empty.</span>
          </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

And i replace them for this:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty requestScope['nameList'] }">
    <c:forEach var="name" items="${requestScope[' nameList '] }">
      Name:${name.name }
        <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${not empty nameList.phoneList }">
            <c:forEach var="phone" items="${nameList.phoneList }">
              Phone:${phone.phone } </div>
            </c:forEach>
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
         <span>The phone list is empty.</span>
          </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

The phoneList is in every name object of the nameList that I have established in the request.
  When i loop the nameList i can access to the phoneList using the expression:

```
${nameList.phoneList}
```

I hope my English is correct.